# How to change the value of a variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, blackjack

I am working on a simple blackjack game and am trying to change the value of variable 'dealer_value3' from "A"string to an integer of either 11 or 1 depending on the dealers hand. My current code keeps giving me an error.

```
if dealer_value3 == "A"
 if dealer_hand1 < 11
  return dealer_value3 = 11
 else
  return dealer_value3 = 1
 end
end
```

Comment: What error does it generate? What's the value of `dealer_hand1` variable?

Comment: This code makes no sense, you assign to a local variable and then *immediately* `return` which exits the method and makes all local variables go out of scope anyway, so why do the assignment at all? Your code is equivalent to `if dealer_value3 == "A" then return if dealer_hand1 < 11 then 11 else 1 end end`.

Comment: can you show us more of your code? where is dealer_value3 declared for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

It's best to think of variables outside of the constructs of our other code.

Ruby's variables require very little code / syntax.

We can create a variable by stating it's name, an `=` sign or call an assingment and a value.

`count = 1`

Our variable name is `count` and its value is assigned to `1`

We can reassign count at anypoint in time (if it's within scope (don't google this yet))

```
count = 1
puts count # => 1

count = "bananas"
puts count #=> "bananas"
```

**Your use of return is what is causing your particular problem**  `return` can only be used within a method so within.

```
def a_method
  return 1
end

puts a_method # => 1
```